# Putting a path received from os.walk into a cmd to run on Windows terminal - python

Tags: python, terminal, path, backslash

I have problematic code that looks like the following:

```
def optimizer(dst, directory = r"G:\Attachments\Attachments" ):
    dst = " /d " + dst
    reducer = '"' + r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ORPALIS\PDF Reducer 3 Professional Edition\pdfreducer.exe" + '"' + " /q 2"

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        src = r" /f " + path
        cmd = reducer + src + dst
        subprocess.call(cmd)

optimizer(r"C:\Users\Desktop\ReducedPdfs")
```

What I'm trying to do is go through all directories in the given directory and optimize pdfs using this command:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\ORPALIS\PDF Reducer 3 Professional Edition\pdfreducer.exe" /q 2 /f G:\Attachments\Attachments /d C:\Users\Desktop\ReducedPdfs`.

The problem is with the *path* variable that I use when I parse this command together in the above method.  If I leave it as it is returned from os.walk, it's a normal string and then the slashes are seen as escape sequences.  If I wrap it in a repr(), then it gets put into the PDF Reducer software with leading and trailing single quotes (') and double back slashes, which the program doesn't know what to do with.

I tried replacing the backslashes with forward slashes with re.sub() and .replace() to no avail. re.sub() doesn't seem to work with escape characters very well and when I used .replace(), then my program didn't run.  With repr(), it runs, but says the file doesn't exist in the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess` commands work best as a list of arguments instead of just a long string, this helps avoid certain issues (like escape sequences, paths with spaces in them, quotations, etc.)

You should use something like this (and modify to fit your needs):

```
cmd = [reducer, '/q', '2', '/f', path, '/d', dst]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Note that if this is how you use it, paths like `path`, `dst` and `reducer` do NOT need to be surrounded in quotes even if they have spaces in them, because you already specified that they are a single item in this list.

This is how it should look like in your code:

```
def optimizer(dst, directory = r"G:\Attachments\Attachments" ):
    reducer = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ORPALIS\PDF Reducer 3 Professional Edition\pdfreducer.exe"

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        cmd = [reducer, '/q', '2', '/f', path, '/d', dst]
        subprocess.call(cmd)

optimizer(r"C:\Users\Desktop\ReducedPdfs")
```

If you need to filter out only those subfolders that contain pdf files, do something like this:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    if any(f.endswith('.pdf') for f in files):
        cmd = [reducer, '/q', '2', '/f', path, '/d', dst]
        subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Or alternatively, a faster version of the above without `os.walk` (using `pathlib`):

```
from pathlib import Path
paths = {str(f.parent) for f in Path(directory).rglob('*.pdf')}
for path in paths:
    cmd = [reducer, '/q', '2', '/f', path, '/d', dst]
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion to make my code cleaner, however unfortunately it did not solve the issue.

Comment: If I make your suggested adjustment, my cmd that I'm sending to subprocess.call looks like this: ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ORPALIS\\PDF Reducer 3 Professional Edition\\pdfreducer.exe', '/q', '2', '/f', 'G:\\Attachments\\Attachments', '/d', 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ReducedPdfs'], which is still problematic because the pdfreducer doesn't know what to with \\s in the path.

Comment: Your suggestion still has me passing in variables - like "path" that don't end up in the right format for pdfreducer to read

Comment: I don't get an error, but the program just sits there and doesn't do anything, whereas if I run it using a path that is a deeper folder inside of G:\Attachments\Attachments, like G:\Attachments\Attachments\150\-1000155356 for example, pdfreducer comes up right away and reduces all of the pdfs in that folder

Comment: That behavior would make me think that os.walk is not working properly, but if don't run the subprocess.call() and just print out the path and files, os.walk **is** running through all the files in all the folders recursively.

Comment: I think the program hangs only if it tries to call the program on a folder that doesn't contain any PDFs. It's not `os.walk` fault if that's the case. I edited the answer to try and filter out only the correct folders, please try it

Comment: I would just suggest one edit to the code to filter out pdfs - currently it loops through all of the paths and makes a list of paths with pdfs, then it goes through the whole list **again** and runs the command - O(N^2). If we just wrote a simple loop instead, we could look for files with the .pdf extension **and** run the subprocess.call() in the same loop - O(N)